# Is there a way to save html text to a file in google drive using apps script?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, converters, google-drive-api

Is there a way to save html text to a file in google drive using apps script? My app sends back an html string, which I want to save as an .html file into drive, as if I'd uploaded an HTML file to drive. I then intend on opening this .html file as a google doc, which will convert it to a doc format. I've tried this procedure manually, and it works well. Just need to do it in a script.

More to the point, I'd love a direct way to convert HTML into a google doc.

Answer (score 2):

```
var url = 'YOUR PAGE';
var p = SitesApp.getPageByUrl(url);
var html = p.getHtmlContent();
var blob = DriveApp.createFile('dummy',html, 'text/html').getBlob();
var resource = {
  title: 'YOUR FILE NAME',
  convert: true,
  mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.document' 
};
Drive.Files.insert(resource,blob);
```

Comment: Make sure to activate Drive API and see https://plus.google.com/104403800912062884925/posts/bWZ74KxW2UU

Comment: Please, explain your answer, What it does, why, how... something

Comment: this actually works but it is indeed missing a few words of explanation !

Comment: Thx for the reminder. Get the html source e.g. from a Google site page. Create a blob using DriveApp with Mime type 'text/html' and use the Drive API to convert this classified blob into a Google document. This schema will work for other Mime types too.