# How to control calendar options while opening using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm playing around with activating Google Services from GAS using an UiApp.

This can be achieved by using an anchor, with or without an image of a button

[How to show an email message content using GAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039654/how-to-show-an-email-message-content-using-gas) shows how an email can been shown this way.

Now I would like to use the same technique for displaying a calendar.

```
var calendarUrl     = 'https://www.google.com/calendar/render?tab=mc';
var calMainUrl      = 'https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=myEmailAddress@gmail.com'
var calHolidaysUrl  = 'https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=en.dutch%23holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com';
var calBirthdaysUrl = 'https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=%23contacts@group.v.calendar.google.com';

   var url = calendarUrl;  // or any of the other urls above
   app.createAnchor('Open Agenda', url);
```

It works, but I would like to get control over the various possibilities of the calendar shown, like starting in '2 weeks' view or 'not showing hours between 0 and 7'

Does anybody know what (and how) parameters can be provided to the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options implicitely described in the Google Calendar parameters... see screen captures below (sorry this is in french maar u zal waarschijnlijk begrijpen).
When you change options there you can see the result in the HTML block shown on the parameter page.

[image]

clicking this leads to this screen :

[image]