# google script to backup web page each day as a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I need a google script which will automatically backup one particular web page every day in the Google Drive and save it as Spreadsheet if it's possible.

I think that I need to combine somehow these two scripts and that is all I need.

https://ctrlq.org/code/19687-backup-web-pages-daily-google-scripts

[Is there a way to save html text to a file in google drive using apps script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22236558/is-there-a-way-to-save-html-text-to-a-file-in-google-drive-using-apps-script)

Could someone combine that please?

Comment: Curious- why will this script not work for you? Https://ctrlq.org/code/19687-backup-web-pages-daily-google-scripts

Comment: @OblongMedulla
I've enter the link in RESOURCE_URL = 'my link', and folder name in BACKUP_FOLDER_ID = 'my folder name',
and also created folder my folder name in google drive. But after I run createBackup function I get the info that isn't possible to find item with that ID or that I haven't got permission to access it (line 36).

Comment: I find out that in BACKUP_FOLDER_ID = I must use folder ID, not folder name, and I find here what is folder ID in google drive: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FT3XSmekrc
Now I just need to edit this script: https://ctrlq.org/code/19687-backup-web-pages-daily-google-scripts
because I want that every new file is saved within "main folder named backup", and not to every file save into new folder.

Comment: It Looks like you can just change the foldername here:  FOLDER_NAME = "Backup",

Comment: @OblongMedulla FOLDER_NAME = is defined in line 13, but I have before FOLDER_NAME_FORMAT = 'yyyy-MM-dd', in line 5. If I delete line 5, and define  FOLDER_NAME = "Backup", in line 13 I get folder Backup inside main folder Backup. I don't want new folder format yyyy-mm-dd for every new file or backup folder inside backup folder for every new file. I want only every new file named in format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:00:00 inside main folder named Backup. Could someone please help me with that? And also if is possible to save the text content from web page not in html but in xlsx format.